# Does google/go dev.boringcrypto branch contains FIPS certified BoringCrypto library?

Tags: go, fips

Go has [dev.boringcrypto](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/dev.boringcrypto) branch that holds the patches to make Go use BoringCrypto.

So, the question is: does [src/crypto/internal/boring/goboringcrypto_linux_amd64.syso](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.boringcrypto/src/crypto/internal/boring/goboringcrypto_linux_amd64.syso) correspond to the FIPS certified BoringCrypto library specified here: [Google's BoringCrypto FIPS 140-2 Non-Proprietary Security Policy](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3678.pdf?)?